# CCSpriteBatchNode children's animations

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When a `CCSprite` child of `CCSpriteBatchNode` performs a `CCAnimation`, are the frames of that animation also batch drawn just like the main image of CCSprite? If not, is there a way to have all the frames of many animations of many batch node children all be batch drawn together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CCAnimation simply changes the sprite frame of the sprite. In essence it simply changes which part of the (much bigger) texture atlas the sprite is displaying. So animations are properly sprite-batched because you're just changing which part of the texture the sprite is displaying.

Comment: Is it safe to say then that your animation frames must be part of the same texture as the CCBatchNode or you will throw errors?